# DIsplay content of textfield into a label

Tags: iphone

I am working with UITextfield.I need to Display content of textfield in to a lable and according to the text entered,the height and width of label should change.
   Can somebody help me   and post a simple implementation of a UILabel according to my requirement that works fine?
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use this code wherever you want. It adjust size of UILabel according to entered text.**

```
yourString = textField.text;

CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font 
                    constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                    lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode]; 

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = yourLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: thanks a lot..my code is working after replacing newFrame.size.height by  newFrame.size.width